# JDBC4 Hive Driver error: Only AEQuery is supported

Tags: java, jdbc, hive

I'm trying to execute a simple hiveql statement like the following: insert into table1 select * from table2.

Both tables have the same schema but different store options, that is, table1 is stored as avro and table2 as parquet.

I copied jdbc4 driver to project's location and I can obtain a connection to hiveserver2 without any issues. However, when I try to execute the above query, the following exception occurrs.

```
Only AEQuery is supported.
java.sql.SQLException: Only AEQuery is supported.
    at com.cloudera.hive.hive.querytranslation.HiveQueryTranslator.translate(HiveQueryTranslator.java:86)
    at com.cloudera.hive.hive.querytranslation.HiveQueryTranslator.translate(HiveQueryTranslator.java:74)
    at com.cloudera.hive.hivecommon.dataengine.HiveJDBCDSIExtQueryExecutor.execute(HiveJDBCDSIExtQueryExecutor.java:168)
    at com.cloudera.hive.jdbc.common.SStatement.executeNoParams(SStatement.java:2719)
    at com.cloudera.hive.jdbc.common.SStatement.execute(SStatement.java:549)
    at py.com.personal.hive.HiveDataLoad.insert(HiveDataLoad.java:46)
    at InsertTest.testHiveInsert(InsertTest.java:23)
Caused by: com.cloudera.hive.support.exceptions.ErrorException: Only AEQuery is supported.
```

Can somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong or how this can be solved?

This is my code:

```
if (this.conn == null) {
    this.conn = this.cm.connect();
}

Statement stmt = this.conn.createStatement();
String sql = "INSERT INTO " + toTable + " SELECT * FROM " + fromTable;
stmt.execute(sql);
stmt.close();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is you are missing keyword **[TABLE](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-InsertingdataintoHiveTablesfromqueries)**  from isert into command.

```
  String sql = "INSERT INTO **TBALE** " + toTable + " SELECT * FROM " + fromTable;
```

Comment: Thanks @sandeep rawat, it was definitely that missing keyword the one causing the issue, it is now working properly :)